# Hashing with SHA512

Tags: laravel, api

I have a table for Api end points called smsmo and the Models Class is Smsmo with these fields:

**Smsmo:**

```
customer code varchar(30),
customer phone varchar(30),
customer name varchar(30),
customer address varchar(30),
customer hash varchar(300)
```

While trying to Save or update, these fields (phone, code, name) to be hashed into hash field.

```
hash = name + code + phone
```

Already I have these Api:

**ApiController:**

```
public function indexSmsmo()
{
    $smsmos = Smsmo::all();
    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmos], $this->successStatus);

}   

public function showSmsmo($id)
{
    $smsmo = Smsmo::find($id);

    if (is_null($smsmo)) {
        return $this->sendError('SMS Outgoing not found.');
    }        
    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmo], $this->successStatus);
}    

public function storeSmsmo(Request $request)
{
    $smsmo = Smsmo::create($request->all());
    return response()->json(['success' => $smsmo], $this-> successStatus);
}    

public function editSmsmo($id)
{
    $smsmo = Smsmo::find($id);
    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmo], $this->successStatus);
}

public function updateSmsmo(Request $request, $id)
{
    $smsmo = Smsmo::find($id);
    $smsmo = $smsmo->update($request->all());
    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmo], $this->successStatus);
}

public function deleteSmsmo($id)
{
    $smsmo = Smsmo::find($id)->delete();
}
```

So how do I hash using SHA512 and the functions above before sending the endpoints.

Comment: SHA-512 is a cryptographic (one-way) hash function, so there is no direct way to decode it. The entire purpose of a cryptographic hash function is that you can't undo it. still you would like to do this ?

Comment: yes. I still want to do the hashing in my api

Comment: So in database, the field would be in normal form... but when you supply to api you just need to make these values as sha-512 correct?

Comment: Please can you give me a sample based on what I have sent

Comment: please reply to above comment.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a [built-in](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.hash.php) `hash()` function that covers many algorithm including `SHA-512` so something like this should work:

```
public function storeSmsmo(Request $request)
{
    $smsmo = new Smsmo;
    $smsmo->fill($request->all());
    $smsmo->hash = hash('sha512', $smsmo->name.$smsmo->code.$smsmo->phone);
    $smsmo->save();
    return response()->json(['success' => $smsmo], $this-> successStatus);
}    

public function updateSmsmo(Request $request, $id)
{
    $smsmo = Smsmo::find($id);
    $smsmo->fill($request->all());
    $smsmo->hash = hash('sha512', $smsmo->name.$smsmo->code.$smsmo->phone);
    $smsmo->save();
    return response()->json(['success' => true,'data'=>$smsmo], $this->successStatus);
}
```

Alternatively, you can improve code reusability by extending model life-cycle:

```
class Smsmo extends Model
{
    ...
    public static function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        static::saving(function ($model){
            $model->hash = hash('sha512', $model->name.$model->code.$model->phone);
        });
    }
    ...
}
```

In a nutshell, anything you define inside `static::saving()` will always be executed before saving the `Smsmo` model. By this method, you don't have to make any change in your controller.

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Laravel Mutator** for this.

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Smsmo extends Model
{
    /**
     * Set the hash attribute.
     *
     * @param  string  $value
     * @return void
     */

    public function setHashAttribute($value)
    {
        $hash = $this->phone.$this->code.$this->name;
        $this->attributes['hash'] = hash('sha512', $hash, false);
    }
}
```

No need to change in your controller function.

Here is the documentation for more details. https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators

Comment: I think this is is a bit weird. You still need to call the mutator from the controller and without arguments. The best way to automate this is by extending/hooking model life cycle

Comment: @YohanesGultom why you call mutator? Also the big question how you call mutator? As per Laravel documentation it would be call `automatically`.

Comment: Also I'm curious to know, how you found this as weird? I think this is the better solution to set a model property from one place. And you don't need to worried about to make changes for each request.

Comment: Well, you can give it a try yourself. This is from the doc: "The mutator will receive the value that is being set on the attribute, allowing you to manipulate the value and set the manipulated value on the Eloquent model's internal $attributes property" https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor. So in this case, `$smsmo->hash = '';` needs to be called from controller.

Comment: Sometimes `after edits` makes the other statement incorrect...so for better add new :)

Comment: @YohanesGultom specify the reason to downvote the ans. It's not good to downvote if you feels pulling down.

Comment: Based on my arguments above, I've explained that your solution is not what the asker needs and a bit misleading. Sorry, no offense. Rest assured, if my opinion is wrong, I'm sure others will upvote you

Comment: Really? hopefully in future you must have valid reason :)